# SwiftUI @Binding didn't update display alert

Tags: swiftui

I trying to display an alert after dismiss the sheet. But when I update the @Binding in the sheet, the alert in home page didn't appear. I don't know what's the problem now. Anyone can explain to me? Is it the problem of using @Binding? If the method/logic of doing this is wrong, what method should I use?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State var showAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("sheet")
                .onTapGesture(perform: {
                    self.showSheet.toggle()
                })
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            AddView(showAlert: self.$showAlert, showSheet: self.$showSheet)
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert){
            Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("Wear sunscreen"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
        }
    }

}
struct AddView: View {
    @Binding var showAlert: Bool
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss") {
            self.showSheet = false
            self.showAlert = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sheet has different context, so alert set up like in original code is not visible there.

Here is modified code that works. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State var showAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("sheet")
                .onTapGesture(perform: {
                    self.showSheet.toggle()
                })
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, onDismiss: { self.showAlert = true }) {
            AddView(showSheet: self.$showSheet)
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert){
            Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("Wear sunscreen"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
        }
    }

}
struct AddView: View {
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss") {
            self.showSheet = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How if I want to change the showAlert in the sheet? Something like trigger by anything but not only dismiss?

Comment: As I wrote sheet has different view hierarchy context, and you cannot show alert attached out of sheet view hierarchy, like in your original post. You can easily test this - instead of dismiss sheet on button just try to show alert... So, if you need to show alert over sheet you have to use different alert modifier within AddView.

Answer (score 2):

The real problem is that you are trying to dismiss the sheet and show the alert at the same time. In your code, if you add a 0.5 second delay to the alert, it will work:

```
struct AddView: View {
        @Binding var showAlert: Bool
        @Binding var showSheet: Bool

        var body: some View {
            Button("Dismiss") {
                self.showSheet = false
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    self.showAlert = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, it's much cleaner to write it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State var showAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showSheet.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("sheet")
            })
            .accentColor(.primary)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, onDismiss: showAlertFunction, content: {
            AddView()
        })
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert){
            Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("Wear sunscreen"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
        }
    }
    
    func showAlertFunction() {
        showAlert.toggle()
    }

}

struct AddView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss") {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. May I know why must delay it? Can you please explain a bit? thank you.

Comment: I don't know the technical answer. This happens often in SwiftUI when you try to show 2 things at the same time (Alerts, ActionSheets, Sheets, FullScreenCovers, etc.). It seems like Xcode gets confused which view is showing on the screen. I believe here, you were trying to show an Alert on the first screen, while the user is on the second screen and since Xcode knows you're on the second screen, it won't show the alert on a background screen. By delaying 0.5 seconds, you give time for the second screen to dismiss so when you try to show the alert, it's already on the foreground screen.